# Why isn't Vagrant binding my Django/Wagtail server?

Tags: django, vagrant, wagtail

I was following the tutorial [here](http://wagtail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started/using_vagrant.html) and got to the point where I called `djrun` and found nothing happening on `http://localhost:8000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to making sure that Django's runserver is properly bound `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`, you also need to check to see if Vagrant is forwarding the port for the host machine. This can be seen as a part of the STDOUT which comes from the `vagrant up` command:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'wagtail-base-v0.3'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: gilles_default_1431922616155_88032
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8000 => 8111 (adapter 1) # <== This is the relevant line.
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
```

The server is located, therefore, at [`http://localhost:8111/`](http://localhost:8111/)

### Edit

Per the comment below, you can also set this value through the Vagrant configuration file. The config key is called `config.vm.forwarded_port`. Below is the start an example file (as provided by Wagtail by default):

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
    # Base box to build off, and download URL for when it doesn't exist on the user's system already
    config.vm.box = "wagtail-base-v0.3"
    config.vm.box_url = "http://downloads.torchbox.com/wagtail-base-v0.3.box"

    # Forward a port from the guest to the host, which allows for outside
    # computers to access the VM, whereas host only networking does not.
    config.vm.forward_port 8000, 8111 # <-- This is the relevant line.
```

Comment: Alternatively, just check the Vagrantfile for `config.vm.network "forwarded_port"`